# Sql server or Mongodb need some suggestions

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb

Ok so far i have used relational database for almost all my applications.But the current task which i am about to do raises eyebrows in terms of load.

My current scenario which i would like to implement : I have a list of 1.5k hotels which will share their inventories (room type/availability) for an year (365 days)

Assuming that there will be at least 3 room types per hotel so my calculation is

1500 * 3 * 365 = 1642500 records

How this works ?

For an entire year we as an OTA partner will get inventories from a list of hotels so every time a booking is done then we will have to update the records based on date of booking.So considering the above situation would sql server be easy to handle this much of data inserted ? or i want to consider moving to document database.Or is there any other solution that could be much easier to implement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are asking if sql server can handle 1.6M records? Yes it can, easily.

Comment: It is a database. It's all it does. And it does it good. https://dzone.com/articles/mongodb-facts-over-80000 Here article describe that DB insert 80k ins per secunde (but that is relative). So in that case 1.65M/80k database would inserted your records in 20 sec.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about performances I suggest you to use Mongodb. its more fast when you have to manipulate huge data. and also you can easily upgrade your entity since it's a schemaless.

you can check this link for performance comparaison between the two of them :
https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2010/04/29/mongodb-vs-sql-server-2008-performance-showdown/